# How to set the UISlider slide range?

Tags: ios, uislider

How to set the UISlider slide range?
If the UISlider'range is [0,100],How to set the UISlider slide between range[10,90]?

Many thanks~

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10701693/1648976

Comment: Why would you want a range from `[10,90]` do you want to the slider to display the `10` at the beginning and and? otherwise you could do with `[0,80]`

Comment: Hello,I wana to user UISlider to customize a CustomizeSwitch,like UISwitch,and the thumb image should start at 10 and end at 90,many thanks for ur help~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your slider is named "slider"

You would just do :

```
slider.minimumValue = 10;
slider.maximumValue = 90;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
_slider.minimumValue = minValue;
_slider.maximumValue = maxValue;

_slider.value = yourValue;
```

Comment: As you share,I programming like that,but sound like that the thumb can slide <10 and >90.

Comment: Well, that's how you do it. Add an *IBAction* from interface builder to your .h with "sliderValueChanged", and put *NSLog("%f", _slider.value)* in it. It will log the value of the slider when you slide the handle.